# Winword: Connection to Word Add-In (dotm file) does not stick after closing and re-opening Word file

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I have written some Word macros stored in an .dotm file saved in a folder on my computer (not the default personal folder of Word).

I then went to File - Options - Add-Ins - Word Add-In and connect to this file.

[image]

Now I can run macros from the .dotm file

I then save, close and re-open the Word file. But everytime I do so, I have to reonnect to the .dotm file again.

Anyway to make this connection permanent?

I tried to trust Add-In and added this folder to Trusted Locations in Word Options but that did not help.

Comment: As far as I know, it's a default behavior of Excel by design. Reference: [Load or unload a template or add-in program](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/load-or-unload-a-template-or-add-in-program-2479fe53-f849-4394-88bb-2a6e2a39479d).

Comment: Thanks @HerbGu_MSFT. I am talking about Word not Excel. In Excel, the connection is permanent once established. Why it does not work for Word?

Comment: Sorry, that's my typo. It's Word.